# Is there a shorter way to write many WHERE clauses for single column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE UPPER(column) = 'STRING1'  
   OR UPPER(COLUMN) = 'STRING2' 
   OR UPPER(COLUMN) = 'STRING3' 
   OR ... 
   OR UPPER(COLUMN) = 'ANYSTRING';
```

Here you can see that `UPPER(column)` is compared with multiple strings (strings are arbitrary). The query becomes massive as the number of strings to compare increases.

I'm wondering if there is some shorter way to write this query, maybe something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE UPPER(column) = ('STRING1' OR 'STRING2' OR ... OR 'ANYSTRING')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?, does it probably support the `... WHERE UPPER(column) IN ('STRING1', 'STRING2', 'ANYSTRING')` syntax?

Comment: You probably don't need `UPPER()` at all, if your table uses a case-insensitive collation. It's not clear from your question which brand or version of SQL database product you are using, or which collation you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from users
where upper(column) in ('STRING1', 'STRING2', ... 'ANYSTRING')
```